# SQL - Return Columns with a specific value

Tags: sql-server-2005

Before I ask my question will layout what I'm trying to do.

I have this table such as below

```
Columns -  PID, Choice1, Choice2,......Choice10
Rows -     1,X, O, X, O.........
```

Ive been searching on the net for quite some time and need a little push in the right direction if what I'm trying to do is possible.  While getting the coding will help me with the small project I'm doing, it doesn't really help me learn more about SQl.

Is it possible to do a search on the table and return only the columns that have a value of X where PID = some value??

My gut instinct is saying no and I might have to restructure my database to accomplish what I'm doing.  As i said a point in the right direction where I can read up on what I'm trying to do is great, getting the coding for it.. really doesn't help me learn it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you should restructure your database, but you can use PIVOT and UNPIVOT to transpose and restructure the output table. Columns are normally fixed with a variable number of rows depending on the WHERE clause. Using PIVOT can swap columns for rows, giving you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up with PIVOT & UNPIVOT, will be doing some more research on these topics to see if it will help me in the long run or restructuring my database will be my best route.